# What is correct way to get ONE screenshot/snapshot of a video using xuggler?

Tags: java, video-capture, xuggler

I want to create an image from a video using xuggler. The sample code provided generates images from video in an interval, I modified it so that it only generates one image from video. BUT, it looks like it is actually looping through the whole video rather than just taking a snapshot of a specific time then end.

How can I properly generate ONE image from a video without looping through the whole video? On shorter videos this is fine but on hr+ videos, this would become a huge problem.

Below is my code:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import java.io.File;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Random;

import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaReader;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaListenerAdapter;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.event.IVideoPictureEvent;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.Global;

public class Test extends MediaListenerAdapter {
    public static final double SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES = 1;
    public static final long MICRO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES = (long)(Global.DEFAULT_PTS_PER_SECOND * SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES);

    private int mVideoStreamIndex = -1;
    boolean takeImage = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test("src/main/Wildlife_ 512kb, hkf.mp4");
    }

    public Test(String filename) {
        System.out.println("starting the xuggler");
        IMediaReader reader = ToolFactory.makeReader(filename);
        reader.setBufferedImageTypeToGenerate(BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
        reader.addListener(this);
        while (reader.readPacket() == null) { do { } while(false); }
    }

    public void onVideoPicture(IVideoPictureEvent event) {
        try {
            if (event.getStreamIndex() != mVideoStreamIndex) {
                if (-1 == mVideoStreamIndex) {
                    mVideoStreamIndex = event.getStreamIndex();
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }

            if (event.getTimeStamp() > MICRO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES && takeImage) {
                Random random = new Random();
                File file = new File("/Users/yao/__TEMP__/media_upload_temp/" + random.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE) + ".png");
                ImageIO.write(event.getImage(), "png", file);

                double seconds = ((double)event.getTimeStamp()) / Global.DEFAULT_PTS_PER_SECOND;
                System.out.printf("at elapsed time of %6.3f seconds wrote: %s\n", seconds, file);

                takeImage = false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, I just aded a boolean field and use that to manage when to break out of loop/video after one image was capture.

```
 while (reader.readPacket() == null) {
                if (!takeImage) {
                    reader.removeListener(this);
                    break;
                }
            }
```